# Can a session expire during the page processing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to solve a problem where the session id seems to clearing mysteriously during postback. I am sure that the value is being set and there is no other place in my code where i am clearing that session.  Also, I am storing the value of the session id in my page's viewstate. During the postback the viewstate is empty which essentially means that when the value was assigned to viewstate the session variable was null. Is it possible that  during code execution, session object is cleared because of timeout?

So lets say if i have following code.

```
if (session["id"] == null)                                        :line1
{                                                                 :line2
   session["id"] = // Generate some unique id                     :line3 
}                                                                 :line4

viewstate["id"] = session["id"];                                  :line5
```

is it be theoretically possible that even though session["id"] is not null in line1 it is null on line5 because of time out.

Comment: At what point in the page's life cycle are you using this code (Page_Load, etc.)?

Comment: Is it shared hosting? Is it one long running operation or more, in between? How much time the operations in between take average?

Comment: Did you try debugging through the code to check the value of session["id"] at various breakpoints?

Comment: @TimS.VanHaren: This code is in page_load

Comment: Do you have your session mode set to 'off'?

Comment: @Belmiris: No, the session mode is not off, though we have set it to expire after 25 min.

Comment: @Belmiris Tried this one too, an exception is thrown if it is.

Comment: @Kash:No. It is happening very randomly and not consistently during every postbacks.

Comment: @Rolice: By shared hosting, I am assuming you are referring to webfarm configuration. If thats true then yes its a shared hosting. Between checking the session["id"] = null and assigning that value to viewstate, there is no other process running that would take long.

Comment: Do have any file operations in the web site directory, that would make the application to restart? On shared hosting it is possible (in case of long running operations) the server (IIS) to recycle your w3wp (worker process) on configured time, but this might be some error in the code (logical), example NullReference etc., as you say there is not much code or long running operations.

This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx - see register/unregister object and on the global.asax - OnError add  `Server.ClearError();` to clear the error.

Comment: You shouldn't assume session data is disappearing from seeing empty ViewState. Problem could be with ViewState. Try assigning another variable and actually displaying it in the page, not in ViewState.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević: What kind of problem in viewstate would clear the data from viewstate? Any tip would be very helpful.

Comment: Well is your viewstate enabled ?

Comment: Can be plenty of things. Upgrading ASP.NET project from 2.0 to later occasionally creates problems which are hard to find. it could be some HttpHandler, client side script, or you just be could be checking ViewState before it's actually loaded. Rather than guessing, it's better that you install log4net or such solution and try to properly log debug information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna have to say no. I just made a site and set the session timeout to 1 (minute)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Then added a web page with this in the page load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Test"] = "Tester";

        //Should be longer than the 1 minute session timeout
        Thread.Sleep(120001);

        Response.Write(String.Format("Session[\"Test\"] = {0}", Session["Test"]));
    }
```

I tested on the Cassini VS debugger, and on IIS 7 asp.net 4 and in every test the page loads with Session["Test"] = Tester. I also tried recycling the application pool manually during the sleep and got the same results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeph for the very helpful and conclusive proof that session ids don't clear during page processing. Now i can concentrate on other parts of my program that might be causing the bug.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code and it is working properly...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["id"] == null)
            {
                Session["id"] = "abc";
            }
            ViewState["id"] = Session["id"];
            Label1.Text = ViewState["id"].ToString();
            ViewState["id"] = Session["id"].ToString();
            Label1.Text += ViewState["id"].ToString();
        }
```

Change "session" to "Session" and "viewstate" to "ViewState"

Answer (score 0):

No because you would never get to line 5 if a timeout occurred.  The program, service, whatever, would stop running.